# How to restore btrfs snapshot with out reboot?

Tags: btrfs

If I make a btrfs snapshot of my `/` folder as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124075/how-to-make-a-btrfs-snapshot), I can't roll back until I restart the PC, because I can't delete the old btrfs subvolume  with `btrfs subvolume delete @_baroot`. It will simply tell me it's still in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that this is possible or even should be possible without a reboot. The root directory holds some pretty important system parts that shouldn't be changed at runtime. You can either

- copy the files or directories you want to roll back with `cp --reflink`,
- boot a live system and move the snapshot folder around, or
- change the default subvolume ([source](//wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs#Setting_a_default_sub-volume))

  ```
  # btrfs subvolume list /
  ID 258 gen 9512 top level 5 path root_subvolume
  ID 259 gen 9512 top level 258 path home
  ID 260 gen 9512 top level 258 path var
  ID 261 gen 9512 top level 258 path usr
  # btrfs subvolume set-default 258 /
  ```

  and reboot.