# Why the @ in Btrfs subvolume names?

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, snapshot

Fairly short question. Is there any technical reason for having an @ in the name of a subvolume of a Btrfs? What's its function, benefit or cause of problems?

What is the best practice?

Examples:

- [How to make a btrfs snapshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124075/how-to-make-a-btrfs-snapshot#149501)
- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Befehle_Btrfs-Dateisystem/

Answer (score 8):

It's just a convention. The [kernel btrfs wiki's section on subvolumes](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Subvolumes) doesn't mention `@` at all. This discussion on the [debian-boot mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2016/06/msg00003.html) is informative:

> The convention proposed in the upstream btrfs sysadmin guide is
>   identical to the way Fedora names its subvolumes, and I believe it was
>   written by a Fedora developer.  I think the primary rational to
>   diverge from it is to signify that what seem to be directories are not
>   actually directories, but subvolumes.  As I mentioned before the
>   flexibility this FS supports is astounding, and I fear could be a
>   nightmare to support without near self-evident default conventions.  I
>   guess I'll just pick something, and it someone doesn't like it then it
>   can be changed?  I was hoping any strong opinions would come out in
>   this discussion! :-)

This is a convention that OpenSUSE and Debian apparently picked up from Ubuntu, and the idea of using all those subvolumes is attributed by [Colin Watson to Roger Leigh](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/partman-btrfs/master/revision/2). That was in 2010, and in 2011, we already have subvolumes named with `@`, but I can't find online discussions about this during that period. I suppose only [Colin](https://askubuntu.com/users/3228/colin-watson) can answer this now.

Answer (score 2):

The @ is the 'true' root volume. It has a volume ID of 0, not listed when you do `btrfs subvolume list /`. You use this volume to create/delete subvolumes.

```
mount -o subvolid=0 UUID=insert-the-uuid-here /mnt
```

You must mount this hidden root somewhere else to access the subvolumes. You can get the UUID in `/etc/fstab`, it is the one repeated for all the root subvols.

```
# ls /mnt
  @
```

The `/mnt` listing shows an @ directory, under this is the normal `/etc`, `/var`, etc

```
btrfs subvolume delete /mnt/@/whatever
```

or

```
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@/whatever
```

If creating a subvolume, add:

```
UUID=insert-the-uuid-here /whatever btrfs subvol=@/home 0 0
```

to `/etc/fstab`.

Now, `mkdir /whatever`, then you can mount it: `mount /whatever`.

If deleting a subvolume, be sure to remove it in `fstab` and delete the mount point.

Comment: The question was why the root subvol is called `@`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think this is quite the answer. You need to define a root and you cannot use ``/``. So you need another character that indicates "this is the root", is short and follows the unix convention of starting at something like ``/`` instead of something like ``c:\`` (what could be for example ``@root``). So someone thought of a new convention and nobody objected.

Answer (score 0):

For no particular reason, and it is rather offputting. But we have to stick with it to use timeshift. see [also](https://linuxreviews.org/Btrfs): https://linuxreviews.org/Btrfs