# Create BTRFS snapshots of /home when its not set up as a subvolume

Tags: mount, backup, btrfs

I've set up a backup-server that creates daily BTRFS-snapshots of `/` in `/backup/`.

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r / /backup/$(date +%s)  # simplified example
```

I found this to be problematic because the snapshots get bloated by temporary volumes in `/var/lib/docker`. Now I'd like to create snapshots of `/home` only. But this does not work:

```
# btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /backup/$(date +%s)
ERROR: Not a Btrfs subvolume: Invalid argument
```

So I understand I need to make `/home` a subvolume.  I'm unsure whether this means `/home` must be mounted separately. I've looked at other questions like [How to make a btrfs snapshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124075/how-to-make-a-btrfs-snapshot) but they already have `/home` set up for this. How can I migrate this? What are the steps I need to take?

My current devices:

```
# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="39520d46-2e30-4b51-b093-2a3671eb8f52" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="c9b515af-26c9-4809-aee1-680ca5ee7153"
/dev/sda2: UUID="3a994a01-9d92-4e67-8440-284ce24465f8" UUID_SUB="cbb73892-5f50-40f2-b411-37307bcbefc4" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="462e3ffe-2c99-4481-89aa-b3f13f3985dc"
/dev/sdb: UUID="3a994a01-9d92-4e67-8440-284ce24465f8" UUID_SUB="b78ffe6c-c078-4cc5-b4c7-dd3874251394" TYPE="btrfs"
/dev/sda3: PARTUUID="63c9d4dd-0a85-40d6-9e10-3eaffcba4b49"
```

The `/` volume is mirrored on `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Which one is your `/` partition? is it `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sdb`? It is weird that they have the same UUID.

Comment: Maybe the identical UUID is because `sdb` is used to mirror `sda2`. I don't know enough about BTRFS to say whether this makes sense.

Comment: is this a RAID? It shouldn't make a problem I think.

Comment: Yeah, I did `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1` on it.

Comment: It is a bit weird that you have a partition on `sda` and don't have paritions on `sdb`. But it works this way. You can use either of `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sdb` for my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a snapshot of a directory, but only a subvolume.

But it is quite easy to convert `/home` directory to a separate snapshot.

Let's say your `/` is `/dev/sda2`.

**Create a backup of your system first in case you make a mistake!**

To convert your `/home` to a subvolume boot from a LiveUSB and do this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo btrfs sub create /mnt/@
sudo btrfs sub create /mnt/@home
sudo mv /home /mnt/@home
sudo mv / /mnt/@
```

Now you moved your `/` to the `@` subvolume and `/home` to `@home` subvolume.

Now you need to edit `/mnt/etc/fstab` and add mount options to mount the volumes properly. Add `subvol=@` to the line where the `/` is mounted. And create a similar line for `/home` like this:

```
UUID=3a994a01-9d92-4e67-8440-284ce24465f8 /               btrfs subvol=@ 0       0
UUID=3a994a01-9d92-4e67-8440-284ce24465f8 /home           btrfs subvol=@home 0       0
```

The last thing is to chroot to the system and update `grub`:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
exit
sudo umount /mnt
```

If you made everything right and I didn't make a mistake, you should reboot to a working system.

Comment: Yes please how do I convert /home to a subvolume?

Comment: Please add output of `sudo blkid` command to your question to make it easier to write.

Comment: ok added to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the details! I'm curious though, why do I need the `btrfs sub create /mnt/@`? Wouldn't it be enough to just create the extra `@home` subvolume?

Comment: Well it may work this way. But I am not quite sure grub will take it correctly. Using `@` and `@home` is a standard practice. And if you mount the root of the disk, you'll see the `@home` as a directory. That will confuse things too.

Comment: I ended up just reinstalling and doing `rmdir /home; btrfs subvol create /home;` because I fumbled something and didn't want to figure out how to recover :-)

Comment: Using `/` in subvolume names is not good. It may confuse some software. If you reinstall the system from scratch @ and @home will be created by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

```
a correction:

  $ sudo mv /home /mnt/@home

should read

  $ sudo mv /home/* /mnt/@home

otherwise you end up with

  $ ls -r/home
  home
  $ ls -r /home/home
  user1 user2 user2 ..

which will prevent GDM login..
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1246672)